# How to make a stacked bars chart using a single dataset with TDBChart VCL Teechart component?

Tags: delphi, vcl, teechart, delphi-10-seattle

I would like to create a stacked bars chart with `TDBChart` using a single dataset.

As far as i can see if I use `TDBChart` as i choose a stacked chart 2 series are added.

This component seems good to create stacked charts from many datasets, in which each dataset contains data of a specific type.

I make an example to clarify:

let's say I have a dataset (`dtsSalesAllCountries`) with the following info:

- country
- year
- total_sales

in this way in principle i could plot a stacked bars chart in which I see bar per year and the total_sales for each country are stacked.

But `TDBChart` does this through series, so to perform my result i am currently forced to create one series per country (`sqlFranceSales`, `sqlItalysales`, `sqlIndiaSales`, ...)

This is quite unconvenient, each time i sell to a new country i must add a dataset. This is how it looks like with this implementation:
[image: TDBChart Stacked Bars with three datasets]

Please note I need to use `TDBChart` since I use ReportBuilder/TeeChart integration, that is based on `TDBChart`.

In fact what i am looking for is a pivot chart, that is not available in the Report Builder/TeeChart integration.

Is there a way with `TDBCHart` to achieve the stacked bars sales chart i am trying to implement using a single dataset and not one dataset per series?

Comment: Could you not create the datasets programmatically, perhaps base on a DB table of countries? I am sorry, but I am not familiar with TeeChart, so I don't know whether this is feasible or not. It is just an option I would explore if I were in your position.

Comment: @Dsm what you suggest is how i'd try to do it in a VCL application, but since i must do it in Report Builder i am limited by the ReportBuilder/TeeCHart wrapper that basically allows to use TDBChart "out of the box" (basically attach a report builder dataset to a chart series and see it work), so i am trying to undesrtand if there is a way to do it.

Comment: Sorry, with VCL and Delphi-10-seattle tags, I assumed that we were dealing with a VCL application.

Comment: @Dsm i added the reportbuilder tag too, even if it is an ambiguous tag that applies both to MS Report Builder and Digital Metaphors' one.

Answer (score 0):

For TChart itself you would configure the Data Source for the Series as a CrossTab. The extra series will then be created for you. Not sure if it can be done with TCharts embedded in ReportBuilder reports.

[image]

With source data from SQL Server:

```
SELECT * FROM (VALUES ('CA',2012,2500),('US',2012,5600)
                     ,('CA',2013,3000),('US',2013,7000)
                     ,('CA',2014,2600),('US',2014,8000)) 
AS A(Country,Year,Sales)
```

Produces:

[image]