# How to create stacked bar chart in FastReport VCL from one dataset

Tags: vcl, teechart, fastreport

I have dataset with fields «country», «year» and «value», and I want to build bar chart like on this picture:[stacked bar chart example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePM3Y.png)
I can make chart like this in RadStudio for general VCL form as it made in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51418417/how-to-make-a-stacked-bars-chart-using-a-single-dataset-with-tdbchart-vcl-teecha), but not for FastReport report. Or can I bring chart made in VCL form to FastReport?

When I try to make stacked bar chart in FastReport I just not found a way to bild chart with groups. I can make stacked bar chart only from multiple datasets, but number of groups is can vary.